# spring boot without web server but with management server

Tags: spring-boot

we have many services developed with spring boot, some are web services with a servlet container and some are services without a servlet container.
we don't use @EnableAutoConfiguration but we add only the auto configurations we need because our classpath is a mess and full auto configuration may create many beans we don't really need.
on services that don't need a servlet container we still want to have actuator and management server, so we register EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration but it has a condition on web application and does not create the management server.
of course i could just add EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration and just have a servlet container that does nothing but i don't like to do that.
Any idea how to cause spring boot to create the management server even on non web environment?

Thank you